# NServiceBus - put message back on bus

Tags: nservicebus

I have a bus endpoint that processes a message, however I now want to put another message back on to the bus inside this handler.

To do this I need to get a reference to the bus.

However if I try the following:

```
public class ServerEndpoint: IWantToRunAtStartup
{
    public static IBus Bus { get; set; }

    public void Run()
    {
        int x = 5;

        Bus = NServiceBus.Configure.With()
            .DisableTimeoutManager()
            .Log4Net()
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport()
                .IsTransactional(false)
                .PurgeOnStartup(false)
            .UnicastBus()
                .ImpersonateSender(false)
            .CreateBus()
            .Start();

    }

    public void Stop()
    {
    }
}
```

Then I get all sort of config errors, even if I put the Unicast and Msmq Configs in the app.config.

Could anyone provide me with pointers, I'm hoping this is a fairly straightforward mistake!!

Thanks

Duncan

EDIT: This is on the server.  The thing that is confusing me is that the bus gets configured on the web app using the above code, in the global.asax App_Start() method.  But when trying to do this in the ServerEndpoint (the actual 'bus' dll, run inside the host) this doesn't work.

Comment: are you configuring it at client side or at server side, are you using any dependency injection in your project? if yes, try to put the code where you are injecting IBus. The DefaultBuilder() method in configuration tells Nservice bus to use its default DI which is AutoFac

Comment: It looks like you're running the server side using NServiceBus.Host.exe. If that's the case, you don't need any of this code. See the FullDuplex sample for an example of how to set up the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the feedback - I was trying to run before I could walk.

By the looks of things, to send a message to another endpoint, I need to set up a different assembly (ServiceBus.Host).

The Bus is created automatically using DI, so this wasn't the problem after all.

I watched the excellent Pluralsight videos by Andreas Ohlund (http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/nservicebus) and followed the examples he built here (See BusStop - Billing Take 2)

Answer (score 1):

You use Dependency Injection for that, see http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/862398-how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-ibus-in-my-message-handler-

Comment: Thanks, I thought this would happen 'auto-magically' as it is in my web app [I didn't have to do anything for this to create it for me]